# Does iterator need to include any type information from the container by the standard?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

Today I came upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051496/cannot-decode-an-obscured-compiler-error-in-g-when-user-custom-hash-function-i) question and started to wonder about the inconsistencies between gcc/clang and Visual Studio.

The question itself is very general, but still I'd like to understand - does the standard impose any rules on whether the iterator type should or should not contain any container specific type information. Consider this snippet:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

struct hash1
{
    size_t operator()(int key) const
    {
        return key;
    }
};

struct hash2
{
    size_t operator()(int key) const
    {
        return key + 1;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int, hash1> map1;
    map1[1] = 1;
    std::unordered_map<int, int, hash2> map2;
    map2[1] = 1;
    std::unordered_map<int, int, hash2>::iterator it1 = map1.find(1);
    std::unordered_map<int, int, hash2>::iterator it2 = map2.find(1);
    if (it1 == it2) // Visual Studio 2015 Gives an assertion on iterator type inequality
    {
        std::cout << "equal";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "not equal";
    }
}
```

So in Visual Studio the `std::unordered_set` iterator type is simply an `std::list` iterator, which of course does not know anything about the hash function type and thus I can perform the assignment, however then the equality operator gives an assertion since internally it compares the containers. GCC/clang on the other hand also ignore the type incompatibility but there are also no run time warnings/errors.

What does the standard say on this topic?

Comment: Iterators have their properties in standard, rest is implementation dependent. That's why many use `auto` for iterators.

Comment: Say, compiling in Debug or Release mode?  It is possible that in Debug mode, the iterators may have additional code to check for certain inconsistencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pair of iterators describes a **sequence** of values. If you try to do something with two iterators that do not point at elements of the same sequence the behavior of your program is undefined, i.e., the standard doesn't impose any requirements on what the program does.

Note that the previous paragraph doesn't use the word "container" anywhere. Containers are one way of creating sequences, but not the only way. So, no, there is no requirement that iterators know about containers, because iterators have no inherent connection to containers.

Answer (score 2):

The standard doesn't say anything about this. It specifies what operations the type `std::unorderd_map<K, V, H, E, A>::iterator` has to support. Being constructible from `std::unorderd_map<K, V, H1, E, A>::iterator` is not one of them (for `H1` different from `H`). Therefore, the standard places no requirements on how a compiler must treat the program which contains such a construction. So both GCC and VS are fine as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: Yeah, I came down to the same while browsing through cpp reference, but still seems weird to me that the committee works to make code portable, but skips things that break the compatibility.

Comment: This is the so-called SCARY iterators.