# Why does std::map accept a std::pair as key, but std::unordered_map does not?

Tags: c++, hashmap, binary-search-tree, unordered-map, std-pair

Before considering a duplicate, please understand the basis of my question.

Why does a C++ `std::map` accept a `std::pair` as a key type, but a `std::unordered_map` does not?

The first case compiles perfectly:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int,int> int_pair;

int main()
{
    map<int_pair,int> m;

    return 0;
}
```

The second case gives a ton of compile errors.  It has become clear from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685540/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597127/) that a custom hash function and equivalence operator must be created.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int,int> int_pair;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<int_pair,int> m;

    return 0;
}
```

The question here **is not** how to write the hash function for the `std::unordered_map`. The question is, why one is needed at all when `std::map` doesn't require one?

I know `std::map` is a Binary Search Tree (BST), but how exactly are the comparisons being made for that matter between keys of a non-fundamental type (int_pair)?

Comment: `std::map` requires `std::less<T>` whereas `std::unordered_map` requires `std::hash<T>`, simple as that. As to "why" simply look up how to implement a red-black tree (map) vs a hash table (unordered_map), then you'll have your answer.

Comment: see answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590656/error-for-hash-function-of-pair-of-ints?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: `std::map` compiles because `std::pair` has an `operator<` which is called by `std::less` see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp

Comment: @Neargye you didn't seem to understand the question, I was asking about the differences not just why an unordered_map won't compile

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) doesn't hash anything. It uses [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) as its default comparator. It will work for any type that supports `operator<`.

[`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) sorts its elements using a hash provided by [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

It so happens that [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) provides `operator<`, but doesn't have a specialization for `std::hash`.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, essentially it comes down to the fact that `operator<` is provided by `std::pair`

Comment: For those wondering, you can find the [pair operators here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/operators/)